# Proving that $x$ (in interval $[0, 1]$) is rational, iff we could find $n$ that $f^{n}(x) = 0$

Tags: proof-writing, continuity

Let’s assume we have $f$ with the domain $[0, 1]$ with the following definition:

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{t} - \lfloor{\frac{1}{t}}\rfloor$$

and also

$$f(0) = 0$$

Let’s define $f^{n}(x)$ a function that results from a composite function when we combine $f$ with itself $n$ times (like $\underbrace{f\circ f\circ f\dots\circ f}_{n\text{ times}}(x)$.

I want to

a) find out continuous and discontinuous points of $f$;

and

b) prove that $x$ (a number in the interval $[0, 1]$) is rational, if and only if we could find a positive integer $n$ that $f^{n}(x) = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**a)**

The floor function has only discontinous points at whole numbers and therefore $f$ only have discontinous points where $1/t$ is a whole number, except of course possibly for $0$ which is easily seen to be a discontinous point. Also the point $1$ needs some special care, but it's easy to see that it's continuous there anyway.

**b)**

If $x$ is irrational then obviously $f(x)$ is irrational.

So what we need to be proved is that if $x\in\mathbb Q$ then $f^n(x)=0$ for some $n$. But if $x$ is rational $x=a/b$ for some   $a,b\in\mathbb Z_+$, $a<b$ (*). And we can write $b=qa+r$ for some natural $q$ and $r$ such that $0\le  r < a$. By that we have:

$$f(x) = f(a/b) = b/a - \lfloor b/a\rfloor = q+r/a - \lfloor q + r/a\rfloor = r/a$$

So $a/b$ maps to $r/a$ and $r<a$, that is each rational number maps to a rational number with strictly lower nomanator. And therefore eventually chaining the function it will map to $0$ nominator.

(*) This is if $0<x<1$, but we have $f(0)=f(1) = 0$

Comment: Slight quibble: Note that you're explicitly claiming that $a<b,$ which isn't true for $x=1$, and you can't divide by $a$ if $x=0$. It's, of course, trivial to check that these do, indeed, map to $0$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes, that's trivial so I put those cases in an amendment.